# The calculation of permanent of a matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, permanent

The permanent of an $n$-by- $n$ matrix $A=\left(a_{i j}\right)$ is defined as
$$
\operatorname{perm}(A)=\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}} \prod_{i=1}^{n} a_{i, \sigma(i)}
$$
The sum here extends over all elements $\sigma$ of the symmetric group $S_{n}$ i.e. over all permutations of the numbers $1,2, \ldots, n$.
$$
\operatorname{perm}\left(\begin{array}{ll}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{array}\right)=a d+b c
$$
The best known general exact algorithm of computing the permanent is due to H.J. Ryser. Ryser's formula can be evaluated using $\mathrm{O}\left(2^{n-1} n^{2}\right)$ arithmetic operations
$$
\operatorname{perm}(A)=(-1)^{n} \sum_{S \subseteq\{1, \ldots, n\}}(-1)^{|S|} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j \in S} a_{i j}
$$

Is there any method or algorithm to detect a permanent of a square matrix $A(1,-1,0)$ with large even order(1000-1600) zero or nonzero by (super) computer? ( for instance $\left.A_{1000 \times 1000}, A_{1600 \times 1600} \cdot\right)$.
It would be better if it could be calculated out by (super) computer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this #P-complete?

Comment: Computing the permanent of a (0,1)-matrix is #P-complete.  If given a matrix A(1,-1,0), can we detect it zero or nonzero without computing it out  by some methods?

Comment: $A(1, -1, 0)$ means all entries are $1$, $-1$, or $0$?

Comment: yes, it is a (1.-1,0)-matrix.

Comment: We can sort out some cases by noticing that pemanent and determinant are congruent modulo 2. So, if determinant is odd, then permanent must be nonzero.

Comment: That is a good idea. Unfortunately, the permanent of my concerned  (1,-1,0)-matrix is always even， I think.

Comment: Here's a relevant answer from the cstheory stack exchange. https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32885/matrix-permanent-is-0/32887#32887

Of course, this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Also, if permanent of the 0-1 matrix with elements of $A$ taken by absolute value is zero (which is easy to test), then permanent of $A$ is zero as well.